# Amazon Web Service S3 signature

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to fetch product related data from Amazon Product API using this URL mentioned here:

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html

Item Lookup URL:

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS_Access_Key_ID]&Operation=ItemLookup&ItemId=B00008OE6I&Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]&Signature=[Request_Signature]
```

I have entered required details/parameters in URL but I am unable to understand where to get this Signature from or how to generate this signature? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you taken a look on this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html ?